# Quoted text does not wrap in mobile chat

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

When text is quoted with `>` it does not wrap in mobile chat.

[image]

Comment: Well that's just mean.

Comment: Nice freehand circle though.

Comment: The *real* bug is blockquotes being rendered in a monospaced font as if they were code.

Comment: Australian avocados are the reason I don't learn c++

Comment: Quotes are one thing, but the same goes for code blocks! Not good.